# CDF Deploy of dynamic module

Tags: dynamic, sound, cdf-format, cdfplayer

I am trying to deploy a CDF file with a small animation that does the following: when the button is pressed, it plays a sound and displays a spectrogram ; while the sound plays, a red progress line moves across the spectrogram to indicate where we are at.

[image: workin applet]

As you can see in the following screen capture, the code (see below) works fine within Mathematica and in the exported CDF file as long as it’s played by Mathematica. However, when played within the Free CDF Player, I get the correct sound but not the progress line and the graphic is red, which indicates a problem. Sadly, it does not generate any error message.

[image: screen capture]

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
CDFDeploy["test.cdf", DynamicModule[{sound, astream, bg, dim},
   Column[{Dynamic@Show[ImageCompose[bg,
        Graphics[{Red,InfiniteLine[{(.2 + QuantityMagnitude@astream["Position"])/QuantityMagnitude@Duration[sound]*dim[[1, 2]] , 0}, {0,1}]},
                 PlotRange -> dim]], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}],
        Button["Play", AudioPlay[astream]]}],
   Initialization :> (
     sound = ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}];
     astream = AudioStream[sound];
     bg = Rasterize[Grid[{
         {AudioPlot[sound, ImageSize -> 500, FrameTicks -> None]},
         {Spectrogram[sound, ImageSize -> 500, FrameTicks -> None]}
         }]];
     dim = Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[bg]}];
     )]];
```

I tried using `SaveDefinitions` instead of `Initialization` ; I tried exporting directly to a CDF (with the menus) instead of `CDFDeploy`. But the problems is always the same. Thanks !

PS. The motivation for this question : the file is to be deployed to a large community of students that only have access to the *Free* CDF Player but not to Mathematica, nor the Pro Player.

Comment: First check  `DynamicModule`, there are three errors  `Show::gtype: ImageCompose is not a type of graphics.`
`The specified setting for the option GraphicsBoxOptions, PlotRange cannot be used.`
`ConicHullRegion[{Part[$CellContext`dim$$, 1, 2] (0.2 + QuantityMagnitude[$CellContext`astream$$["Position"]])/QuantityMagnitude[Duration[$CellContext`sound$$]], 0}, {{0, 1}}] is not a valid ConicHullRegion specification.`

Comment: @Alex Trounev: that’s strange. I don’t get any of those error messages on MMA 11.3.0.0 (as stated, on my side, it works flawless on MMA, just not in CDF) ; how did you get them ? I don’t call `ConicHullRegion` at least not that I know of so I am curious how can it be quoted in your error message ? I just checked with FullForm: `bg` is an `Image[]` ; I tried changing `bg=Rasterize[...]` to `bg=Rasterize[...,"Graphics"]` so both arguments of `Show` are `Graphics[]` but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Francois Vigneron,  I'm sorry, I checked it again, there are no mistakes. Apparently, there was interference with another program.

Comment: This may help you get the generated error messages while running inside the CDF player: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181013/251

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the initialization and rendering of audio controllers takes enough time to get the front end confused. Here is a slightly changed version which work in cdf. Except the audio plot is not so smooth as in MMA.

```
CDFDeploy["test.cdf", DynamicModule[
  { sound, astream, bg, dim
  , display = ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"]
  }
, Dynamic[display, TrackedSymbols :> {display}]
, Initialization :> (
    sound = ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}];
    astream = AudioStream[sound];
    bg = Rasterize[
      Grid[{{AudioPlot[sound, ImageSize -> 500, 
          FrameTicks -> None]}, {Spectrogram[sound, ImageSize -> 500, 
          FrameTicks -> None]}}]];
    dim = Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[bg]}];
    display = Column[{Dynamic[
        Show[
         ImageCompose[bg, 
          Graphics[{Red, 
            InfiniteLine[{(.2 + 
                  QuantityMagnitude@astream["Position"])/
                QuantityMagnitude@Duration[sound]*dim[[1, 2]], 0}, {0,
               1}]}, PlotRange -> dim]], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}]
        ], Button["Play", AudioPlay[astream]]}])
, SynchronousInitialization -> False
]]
```

Comment: good idea to use `ProgressIndicator` to give the applet something to display while waiting. But sadly your solution still does not work in CDF Player 11.3.0.0 : I get the initial progress bar, but when the main screen kicks in, the image is red and does not show the line at all (like before). Works perfect when MMA opens the CDF, but not when the CDF Player does :-(

Comment: @FrancoisVigneron will try to catch this once I install 11.3 player. I tested on 11.2 and I was able to reproduce the problem as well as the fix was working. Yeah, it is a pain when CDF does not work even if you use with respect to its limitations :/